# Lipschitz-regularity of partition of unity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{U}$ be a finite collection of open subsets covering $K$ satisfying the minimality property: *for every $U\in \mathcal{U}$, the sub-collection $\mathcal{U}-\{U\}$ does not cover $K$.*

*Notation:* Given any subset $A\subseteq K$ denote the relative complement $K-A:=\{x\in K:\, x\not\in A\}$.  Given a point $x\in K$ and a subset $A\subseteq K$ let $\|x-A\|:=\inf_{a\in A} \|x-a\|$.

Is there a condition on the open cover $\mathcal{U}$ such that the partition of unity $\{\psi_U\}_{U \in \mathcal{U}}$ is such that each
$$
\psi_U(x):= \frac{\|x-(K-U)\|^2}{\sum_{V \in \mathcal{U}}\,\|x-(K-V)\|^2}
$$
is Lipschitz?

If so, what are explicit bounds on the Lipschitz constant of the functions $\{\psi_U\}_{U\in \mathcal{U}}$?

Comment: Note that if an open set $U$ can't be removed from the covering $\mathcal U$, i.e. $K\cap U\setminus \bigcup_{U\neq V\in\mathcal U}V\neq\emptyset$, then the $\psi_U$ supported in $U$ in any partition of unity subordinated to $\mathcal U$ must have Lipschitz constant at least 1/diam(U).

Comment: @PietroMajer This I am having a lot of trouble seeing; I was also suspecting that $L=1/r$ where $r>0$ is the Lebesgue number of $\mathscr{U}$.  (Ideally, do you have a reference to this or your claim?)

Comment: Well, what I wrote is just this: if, for a given $x\in K$,  $U$ is the only open set in $\mathcal U$ such  that $x\in U$, then  $\psi_V(x)=0$ for all $V\neq U$,  so $\psi_U(x)=1$; since $\psi_U(y)=0$ on $\partial U$ we need the Lipschitz constant of $\psi_U$ at least 1/diam(U).

Comment: @PietroMajer Ah true, but then can we upper-bound the Lipschitz constant in a similar fashion?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I clarified the notation; I use K-U to denote the complement of $U$ in $K$.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks, its all fixed now; sorry about the typos.

Comment: Explicit upper bounds certainly would depend on the minutiae of the cover. You can see this in the one dimensional case. Let $K = [0,1]$ and there are no upper bound to the Lipschitz constant of $\psi_U$ over the class of all covers of $K$ by pairs of open intervals.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Is there a specific reason to choose the squares of the distance functions rather than the distance functions themselves?

Comment: I'd say it's essentially the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience write

$$ \phi_U(x) = \| x - (K-U)\|. $$

Let $N = |\mathcal{U}|$ the number of open sets in the cover.
Define
$$ f_1(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum \phi_U(x), \qquad f_2(x) = \left( \frac1N \sum \phi_U^2(x) \right)^{1/2} $$
Note that since $\mathcal{U}$ is a cover we have
$$ 0 < f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq \sqrt{N} f_1(x) $$
Let
$$ \delta_1 = \inf f_1, \quad \delta_2 = \inf f_2 $$
and we also have $0 < \delta_1 \leq \delta_2 \leq \sqrt{N} \delta_1 $. Note also that $\delta_1$ is a Lebesgue number of the covering $\mathcal{U}$.

Now, you've defined
$$ \psi_U(x) = \frac{\phi_U^2(x)}{N f_2^2(x)} $$
so
$$ N(\psi_U(x) - \psi_U(y)) = \frac{\phi_U^2(x) f_2^2(y) - \phi_U^2(y) f_2^2(x) }{f_2(x) f_2(y)} $$
$$ = \frac{(\phi_U(x) - \phi_U(y))(\phi_U(x) + \phi_U(y))}{f_2^2(x)} + \frac{\phi_U^2(y) (f_2^2(y) - f_2^2(x))}{f_2(x)^2 f_2(y)^2}. $$
So we have the following estimate
$$ N |\psi_U(x) - \psi_U(y)| \leq \left|\frac{(\phi_U(x) - \phi_U(y))(\phi_U(x) + \phi_U(y))}{f_2^2(x)}\right| + N \left| \frac{f_2^2(y) - f_2^2(x)}{f_2(x)^2} \right| $$

Now, it suffices to consider only those $x,y$ with $\|x-y\| \leq \delta \leq \delta_1$ for a fixed $\delta$. This is because

1. We know that $0 \leq \psi_U(x) \leq 1$ and hence if $\|x-y\| > \delta$, then the corresponding difference quotient is $\leq \frac{1}{\delta}$.
2. On the other hand, if we define
   $$ \epsilon = \inf_{U\in \mathcal{U}} d( U \setminus \cup (\mathcal{U} \setminus \{U\}), K \setminus U ) $$
   then essentially the [same argument of Pietro Majer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424603/lipschitz-regularity-of-partition-of-unity#comment1091500_424603) shows that the Lipschitz constant of the family is at least $1/\epsilon$. (Note: minimality of the covering is used to get that $U\setminus \cup(\mathcal{U}\setminus \{U\}) \neq\emptyset$.) Note that $\epsilon \geq \delta_1$. So we don't expect a much better upper bound estimate of the Lipschitz constant than $1/\delta$.

Now, $\phi_U(x)$ is well-known to be $1$-Lipschitz. So we have that $$\phi_U(x) + \phi_U(y) \leq 2 \phi_U(x) + \delta \leq (2N+1) f_1(x)$$
So
$$ \left|\frac{(\phi_U(x) - \phi_U(y))(\phi_U(x) + \phi_U(y))}{f_2^2(x)}\right| \leq \frac{2N+1}{\delta_2} \|x - y\|  $$
Similarly, we have
$$ |f^2_2(x) - f^2_2(y)| \leq \frac1N \sum |\phi_U(x) - \phi_U(y)| |2\phi_U(x) + \delta| \leq  \|x-y\| \cdot (\delta + 2 f_1(x)) $$
so
$$ N \left| \frac{f_2^2(y) - f_2^2(x)}{f_2(x)^2} \right| \leq \frac{3N}{\delta_2} \|x-y\|$$

So putting everything together we find that the Lipschitz constant of the family $\psi_U$ are uniformly bounded by $6 / \delta_2$.

#### Summary

1. For the finite collection $\mathcal{U}$, each function in the corresponding partition of unity is necessarily Lipschitz.
2. The uniform Lipschitz constant can be controlled by a quantity similar to the Lebesgue number of the covering.

Comment: This has kept me busy for a day. The Lipschitz constant can also be written $6 \sqrt{N} / \delta_1$, which looks like a much better upper bound than what the published literature. Then it finally dawned on me that $\delta_1$ is quite a conservative lower bound for the Lebesgue number. It may generally only be the $N$-th part of the best possible Lebesgue number $\delta_\ast$. The best known bounds actually scale like $N / \delta_\ast$.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why one would use the squares of the distance functions rather than the distance functions themselves?

Comment: I used the square because that's what is used in the original question. @shuhalo Your question is probably better directed to the OP.